# Simple AWS API Gateway passthrough, is it possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'd like to use the AWS API Gateway for an existing API, but the none of the documentation or online tutorials seem to help for this use case. I don't care about Lambda, or serverless APIs, or data transformation, or even authentication right now. I will accept the tedious manual labor involved with setting up a resource and method for each API resource and method. I would like the requests made to the gateway to be passed through to the backend mostly untouched. If the client specifies `Accept: application/vnd.custom-type; schema="http://schemas.example.com/data-type-2.3"`, that accept header should show up at the server. I have managed to get it to forward requests to the right url, but it still can't handle dynamic or custom 'content-type' or 'accept' headers, and isn't passing the request body through. Do I have to set up some kind of complicated mapping templates? Do I have to specify every valid content type and accept type that the API can handle?

I'm starting to wonder if I should give up on AWS API Gateway and try to find something that just does API proxying to various DNS backends, if that exists

Comment: There are api-gw team members who read SO so perhaps one of them will see the question and offer some input.  Although I can think of some reasons, I might suggest that you mention your motivation for this solution in the question for the benefit of others... why would API Gateway be useful to you as a transparent proxy in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly map the Accept and Content-Type headers sent in the method request to the integration request. This will override API Gateway's default behavior for these headers. You will still need to set up resources/methods to match your backend endpoint.

We are working on some new features that will help greatly with this use-case. Stay tuned to the AWS forums in the coming weeks.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to explicitly map every Accept and Content-Type header in API Gateway, just to pass that same header through to the backend?

Comment: No, the values of those headers will be forwarded to the backend integration. Please read the documentation @ http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html#mapping-request-parameters